# Grunt: Destination File Same Name as Source File After Templating

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, npm

I'm trying to template all of the files in a directory and put the result in `bin/admin` directory such that the destination file has the same name as the source file. However, it seems like the `dest` in `data` is the name of file and cannot be specified as a destination directory.

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  grunt.initConfig({
    'template': {
      'process-html-template': {
        'options': {
          'data': {
            'api_url': 'My blog post'
          }
        },
        'files': {
          'bin/admin/': ['src/admin/*'] // <-- Here
        }
      }
    }
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-template');
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['template']);
}
```

What can I do to template all of the files in `src/` and put them in a destination folder with the same name as the source? I tried to use `bin/admin/*` as the destination, but that just create a file with the filename `*` in `bin/admin`. I want to avoid listing all of the files in the source directory manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. It's an object with a src and dest attribute.

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  grunt.initConfig({
    'template': {
      'process-html-template': {
        'options': {
          'data': {
            'api_url': 'My blog post'
          }
        },
        'files': [
          {
            expand:true,
            src: 'src/admin/*',
            dest: 'bin/admin/'
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-template');
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['template']);
}
```